# What is the difference between generic method and generic extension method and extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, difference

What is the difference between **generic method** and **generic extension method** and **extension method**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Generic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) by MSDN.

> A generic method is a method that is declared with type parameters

```
static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs)
{
    T temp;
    temp = lhs;
    lhs = rhs;
    rhs = temp;
}
```

This method swaps the references between lhs (left-hand-side) and rhs (right-hand-side). Because we only want to swap the references and don't care about what the underlying types of the references are, we can declare the method as *a generic method* with type parameter T. This means it can be of any type. This saves us from having to write multiple Swap methods.

```
string s1 = "hello";
string s2 = "world";
Swap(ref s1, ref s2);

int i1 = 5;
int i2 = 12;
Swap(ref i1, ref i2);
```

While the example could be written using object types as Swap method parameters, this would cause an unnecessary overhead with value types known as boxing.

---

[Extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) by MSDN

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.

Let's say we want to extend the existing string class to contain a method for counting words in the string.

```
public static int WordCount(this String str)
{
    return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
}
```

Now we can count words from any string object.

```
string s = "Hello Extension Methods";
int i = s.WordCount();
```

This is especially useful for adding features (methods) to existing classes **which you do not have access to** (from third party assembly, for example).

---

Generic extension methods are simply a mix of the previous two concepts.

Answer (score 1):

**generic method** is called just like regular method, with the difference it can be used for different types by specifying generic type.

```
someObject.GenericMethodFromSameClass<String>();
```

**generic extension method** and **extension method** are similar to each other in a sense that they can be called on objects they extend. Difference between them is the same as difference between regular method and generic method.

```
someObject.ExtensionMethodFromOtherClass();
someObject.GenericExtensionMethodFromOtherClass<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

• Extension Method:
With extension method can add some extra method to specified **type**.
For create extension method

> 1. Definition class with **public static** attribute.
> 2. Definition method in class with **public static** attribute.
> 3. For first parameter of method defined extension method .place before this parameter keyword **this**.

```
public static class TestExtensionClass
{
    public static string TestExtinsionMethod(this string password)
    {
        string encriptedPassword="";
        byte[] ASCIIValues = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
        foreach (byte b in ASCIIValues)
        {
            encriptedPassword += b.ToString();
        }
        return encriptedPassword;
    }
}
```

> 4. In other classes call extension method.

```
       private void CallExtensionMethod()
    {
        string s = "123";
        s.TestExtinsionMethod();
    }
```

•   Generic  Method:
With generic method you can define output type in runtime.
For create extension method

> 1. Definition class.
> 2. Definition method. Before name of method place **T**.
> 3. After name of method place **<**T**>**.

```
     public T TestCastTo<T>(object obj)
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
```

> 4. In other classes call Generic  method.

```
     public static T TestCastTo<T>(this object obj)
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
```

•   Generic  Extension  Method:
•   With combine properties Extension Method and Generic Method you can gain a Generic Extension Method.

```
     public static T TestCastTo<T>(this object obj)
    {
        return (T)obj;
    }
```

in other class call generic extension method

```
    private void CallGenericExtensionMethod()
    {
        string s = "123";
        int i = s.TestCastTo<int>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Methods can be *generic* or *nongeneric*, for example:

```
public void Foo() { }   // Non-Generic Method

public void Foo<T>(T value) { } // Generic Method
```

*Extension methods* are methods used to extend the behavior of types without modifying the type itself. Say you want the `String` type to have a `Reverse` method, you could define an extension method on the String type, like this:

```
public static class ExtMethods
{
    public static string Reverse(this string s) // Non-Generic Extension Method
    {
        // code to reverse string
    }
}
```

Extension methods must be declared *static* and within a *static class*, also its first parameter must have `this` before the type it extends.

Likewise, extension methods can be generic:

```
public static class ExtMethods
{
    public static Foo<T>(this T obj)  // Generic extension method
    {

    }
}
```

So, a *Generic Extension Method* is just an *extension method* that happens to be generic.